# What is ilogb() in c?

Tags: c

What does `ilogb()` do? I looked it up on Google but I didn't understand it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    float num;
    printf("%f",(float)ilogb(125));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
    6.000000
    Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.764 s
    Press any key to continue.
```

Why does it return 6?

Comment: Read [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ilogb.3.html). Then ask a specific question about what you didn't understand.

Answer (score 1):

> What does `ilogb()` do?
>   Why does it return `6`?

When `FLT_RADIX`, defined in `<float.h>`, has value `2`, `ilogb()` returns the position of the most significant `1` in the binary representation of the argument.

For example: `125` is "`0b1111101`"; the most significant `1` is at position 6; `ilogb(125)` returns `6` as your code printed.

Or `0.25` is "`0b0.01`"; `ilogb(0.25)` returns `-2`.

Answer (score 0):

`ilogb()` is a [logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) base 2 operation, but it's meant to be used specifically on floating point numbers, and returns an integer. To understand what it means to [take the exponent part of a floating point number](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ilogb.3.html) you need to know about floating point numbers.

A floating point number isn't just one number, but a combination of three. Even though you write `-333.6`, inside the computer it looks more like `(-1)*(3.336)*(2^2)`, a bit like [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) but using a 2 instead of a 10. So you have one bit for the sign, a few bits for the exponent, and a few for the actual number (the mantissa). This is what the number 125 looks like as a [single-precision floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) which is what `c` uses:

```
0 000110 11110100000000000000000//notice the first digit of the mantissa is missing because it's always 1
(sign = 1) (exponent = 110) (mantissa = 1.111101)
```

In binary, this is `(1)*(1.111101)*(10^110)`, in decimal it is `(1)*(1.953125)*(2^6)`

Back to [`ilogb()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ilogb.3.html): What this does is return the exponent part of the number, in this case `110` which is a `6`.

Comment: `ilogb` uses `FLT_RADIX` as a base, not necessarily two.

Comment: @EricPostpischil While theoretically true, "The value is 2 on all machines we know of except the IBM 360 and derivatives." (from gnu libc/gcc)

Comment: @Ctx: (a) Since you point out examples, the statement is not just theoretically true but practically true. I.e. really and truly true. (b) The prevalence of base two does not justify making false statements. (c) C implementations are not limited to hardware.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Calm down, I just meant to say, that you are practically save with assuming base 2, that's all. In theory, it might fail somewhere, but the chances are next to 0.

Comment: @Ctx: That reasoning allows bugs to occur and is not proper engineering.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Not necessarily, you could for example use an `assert(FLT_RADIX == 2);` to prevent invalid results in the (never occurring) case that it isn't 2.

Comment: @Ctx: Writing an assertion provides a test of the requirement, which is not an assumption of the requirement. The statement “you are practically safe with assuming base 2” is reasoning that allows bugs to occur and is not proper engineering. **Testing** a requirement is good engineering. **Assuming** a requirement is not. There is just no reason to be making false statements about program semantics and teaching students to adopt them.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ok, fine that we found something we can agree on. Thank you for pointing out my improper language.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Your reasoning allows arguments to occur and is not proper communication. Check out the edit history on the original question if you want a bit of perspective. You can nuke a guy for failing to realize there's non-hardware c implementations with base 420.69 floating point numbers, and I can vote close a question for not using the Queen's English. Or you can kindly point out there's some very interesting non-hardware C implementations and I can edit and clarify the question, and provide a decent answer that definitely answers it.

Comment: Having said that, I find FLT_RADIX and IBM 360 machines fascinating and I did not know that.

Comment: Whether an answer uses the queen’s English is not important. Whether an answer contains **true** or **false** statements is. Teaching students false statements is bad.